# Spring MVC Maven Goal not working for GWT 

Tags: gwt, tomcat, maven, spring-roo

I tried to create a very easy Roo Sample Project (the one you find on roo homepage: http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo). It uses GWT and Hypersonic in memory DB.

When i try to use mvn gwt:run everything is ok, but if I use mvn tomcat:run to start tomcat then in my browser I can only see a page with "loading..." in it and nothing happens.

It seems there are no error in tomcat startup.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Any tomcat logs or other hint? Have you tried to deploy another application on this tomcat instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing anything. You cannot use the same Maven goal when you are running a GWT application with Spring MVC.

Depending on your view controllers pick one of the below.

GWT : `mvn gwt:run`

Spring MVC : `mvn tomcat:run`